# How can I compute the inverse digital of a nonrational transfer function?

Tags: transfer-function

My $G(s)=1-e^{-s/\tau}$, $\tau$ is very small, say of order $10^{-4}$.

I need to compute a $H(z)$ (a digital filter) such that $H(z)$ has the inverse response of $G(s)$. Is ok even if $G(z)$ has the inverse response just for $f$<20k.

I don't not also zero and pole go $G(s)$.

I'm able to have an proximation of $H(z)$, but I found it with an iterative algorithm set $H(z)=\dfrac{\alpha}{1 -\beta z^{-1}}$.

I prefer a formal solution.

Comment: Are you sure that your $s$-domain transfer function looks like that? That's a strange form; rational Laplace domain transfer functions would be much more common. I think your TF would correspond to an impulse response of $h(t) = \delta(t) - \delta(t-\frac{1}{\tau})$.

Comment: @JasonR, it's an analog LTI system with some delay.  perhaps SAW (surface acoustic wave) or a long transmission line.

Comment: @robertbristow-johnson: Sounds like reasonable examples.

Comment: To the OP: Note that $G(s)=0$ for $s=0$ (it has a highpass response). Therefore, you won't be able to exactly invert it for $f < 20000\text{ Hz}$, whether you're in the analog or digital domain.